# How to integrate god, sidekiq with capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, sidekiq, god

I am using Rails 4.

I have some background processes running for expiring posts.

sidekiq is being used for background processes. But it halts sometimes in productions. So the jobs can not perform at the exact time.

How to integrate `god`, `sidekiq` with `capistrano` ?

Thanks
Debadatt

Answer (score 1):

When i had similar task, i've used `SV runit`. And in capistrano deploy script, i had something like `sudo sv start sidekiq`

SO basically sv was acting like a service, and all i had to do is just to cd to `current` version folder in my sv script and bundle exec sidekiq -your configs goes here